# cannot find symbol variable java error in my code

Tags: java, variables, compiler-errors

i have the following code that is supposed to set up a Term with an initial value of null, and then return the term as altered through the for loop. 
However when i try to compile gives an error saying cannot find symbol for variable Term (on line 10 at the end of the if statement/for loop).
i don't understand why I am getting this error or how to fix it.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 public Term nextTerm()
   {
   double coefficient = 0.0;
   int exp = 0;
   Term term = new Term(coefficient,exp);
        for (exp = 0; exp < sequence.length ; exp++){
       double[] diffArray = differences();
       if (allEqual() == false) {
           coefficient = diffArray[0]/factorial(exp);
           term = Term(coefficient, exp);
        }
    }
   return term;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
term = Term(coefficient, exp);
```

You get a compilation error because `Term(var1, var2)` is not a valid method available in the class. It should be:

```
term = new Term(coefficient, exp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
term = new Term(coefficient, exp);
```

instead of

```
term = Term(coefficient, exp);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [JLS 15.9. Class Instance Creation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)

> A class instance creation expression is used to create new objects that are instances of classes.
>
> - `UnqualifiedClassInstanceCreationExpression:
>     new [TypeArguments] ClassOrInterfaceTypeToInstantiate ( [ArgumentList] )[ClassBody]`

So change it to following:

```
term = new Term(coefficient, exp);
```